# PlatformIO (with VS Code) Board for Wireless-Tag WT32-ETH01

Tags: platformio

I am trying to start a project with the development board Wireless-Tag WT-ETH01.
PlatformIO IDE asks me to select a board but this board is not on the list. Is there any other board I can chose to continue?

All board models that are supported here but no wireless tag unfortunately.
https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/index.html

Regards,
Emre

Comment: Pick one who's HW is closest. Doc your attempts. Finally make a pull request. Your question should be "How to create support for a new board?" generally.

Answer (score 0):

Should exist, but you might get `Error: Unknown board ID 'wt32-eth01'`

Upgrade of espressif32 resolves this, working part of platformio.ini

```
[env:wt32-eth01]
platform = espressif32@4.2.0
framework = arduino
board = wt32-eth01
```

*There might be better ways to do this, platformio-fu of this answer is low level*

References:
https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/espressif32/wt32-eth01.html
https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32/issues/448
Released in platform-espressif32 v4.2.0 2022-04-29

`board = esp32doit-devkit-v1` is otherwise a possible workaround.